# Signal conditioning circuit for piezoelectric sensor

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, signal-processing, signal-conditioning

I am trying to build a signal conditioning circuit for a [piezoelectric accelerometer](https://assets.rs-online.com/v1699613488/Datasheets/a4bec9145cc21cbb98424742258b4039.pdf). Due to the low output of the accelerometer, I intend to add a signal conditioning circuit to the output.

My idea is to use a charge amplifier to amplify the signal, like so: [image]

I am wondering, however, if other signal conditioning circuits are better suited for this application. Referencing Practical Design Techniques For Sensor Signal Conditioning provides a wealth of information, but none of the designs provided seem superior to the charge amplifier to my mind.

Other [similar questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48816/charge-model-vs-voltage-model-for-piezo-electric-sensor) focus more on the model used to model the PZT, but I want to approach this from a circuitry-based direction. Please let me know if more information is required.